# sequential number with some conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a view with several fields, from **SQL Server 2016**, and I like to put a sequential number if certains conditions meet.
To exemplify, consider this table:

**Table**:

```
GLOBALID | SERVICE_GLOBALID | PHOTO_A_GLOBALID | PHOTO_B_GLOBALID
---------+------------------+------------------+-----------------
EB8F9BE7 | 0CD85BE7         | 490794EC         | 181C5426
EB8F9BE7 | 04405456         | C3A75999         | 5BA26B15
ECF5F7D1 | 8E8A63C2         | 1A225178         | NULL
ECF5F7D1 | 4EB18887         | 2139CF18         | C7B96E0E
```

Some details:

- `GLOBALID` can repeat (because this is a view from several tables with some `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY`);
- `SERVICE_GLOBALID` never repeats;
- `PHOTO_A_GLOBALID` always have a value (never repeats);
- `PHOTO_B_GLOBALID` can have a value, but sometimes is `NULL` (never repeats when have a value).

So, I like to put a sequential number for `PHOTO_A_GLOBALID` and `PHOTO_B_GLOBALID`, but the sequential number must use the two columns from the view. If `PHOTO_B_GLOBALID` is `NULL`, the sequential number must not increment.

This is a result that I want (look at the third row):

**Result**

```
GLOBALID | SERVICE_GLOBALID | PHOTO_A_GLOBALID | PHOTO_B_GLOBALID | SEQ_A | SEQ_B
---------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-------+------
EB8F9BE7 | 0CD85BE7         | 490794EC         | 181C5426         | 1     | 2
EB8F9BE7 | 04405456         | C3A75999         | 5BA26B15         | 3     | 4
ECF5F7D1 | 8E8A63C2         | 1A225178         | NULL             | 5     | NULL
ECF5F7D1 | 4EB18887         | 2139CF18         | C7B96E0E         | 6     | 7
```

I tried with ROW_NUMBER(), but I really don't know how to do this with two columns.

Comment: Do teh numbers assigned actually matter in terms of sequence?  How do we know 1,2 set vs 3,4 set?

Comment: @xQbert I think I don't understand your question. Must be a sequence, from 1 to infinite, in the same order that the rows appear (the order of rows is from a order by date to generate this view).

Comment: you covered it the results are ordered by a date and therefor should be numbered by that dat.e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers show, there is more than one way to do it, but the most direct translation to me would be to count, using the `count` function:

```
select *,
  case
  when PHOTO_A_GLOBALID is not null
  then count(PHOTO_A_GLOBALID)
        over (order by DATE rows unbounded preceding)
     + count(PHOTO_B_GLOBALID)
        over (order by DATE rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
  end,
  case
  when PHOTO_B_GLOBALID is not null
  then count(PHOTO_A_GLOBALID)
        over (order by DATE rows unbounded preceding)
     + count(PHOTO_B_GLOBALID)
        over (order by DATE rows unbounded preceding)
  end
from t;
```

The basic idea is to count all the `PHOTO_A_GLOBALID` values seen up to the current row, and all the `PHOTO_B_GLOBALID` values seen up to the current row, with just slight tweaks to ensure that the current row's `PHOTO_B_GLOBALID` value doesn't affect the computed value for `SEQ_A`.

Now, you can shorten this with the knowledge that `PHOTO_A_GLOBALID` is never `NULL`, but having the same logic for both columns in my opinion makes the query slightly easier to understand.

You can also shorten this with the knowledge that `rows unbounded preceding` is the default when `order by` is specified, but you do need to be explicit for the `rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding` bit.

Comment: your solution worked! But I don't understand from where you get the `DATE` field. This field don't exist on the view. I replaced with `globalid` and worked fine.

Comment: @RobertoCorreia You put in a comment on your question "(the order of rows is from a order by date to generate this view)". If `DATE` is not the field used for ordering, please use the real field that should determine the order instead.

Comment: the example here on stackoverflow is much more simple than the real view (that have 26 columns). I will try to use the `DATE`! tks! (update: worked fine with `DATE`)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

rextester: http://rextester.com/IPBQPM64562

```
if exists (select * from tempdb.sys.objects where name like '#global%') begin; drop table #global; end;
if not exists (select * from tempdb.sys.objects where name like '#global%')
begin
create table #global (globalid varchar(32) ,service_globalid varchar(32) ,photo_a_globalid varchar(32) ,photo_b_globalid varchar(32) ) 
insert into #global values  
    ('EB8F9BE7' ,'0CD85BE7' ,'490794EC' ,'181C5426') 
  , ('EB8F9BE7' ,'4405456' ,'C3A75999' ,'5BA26B15')
  , ('ECF5F7D1' ,'8E8A63C2' ,'1A225178' ,null) 
  , ('ECF5F7D1' ,'4EB18887' ,'2139CF18' ,'C7B96E0E') 
  , ('XXXXXXXX' ,'VVVVVVVV' ,'ZZZZAAAA' ,null) 
  , ('XXXXXXXX' ,'YYYYYYYY' ,'ZZZZBBBB' ,'ZZZZCCCC') 
end;

with cte as (
  select 
      globalid
    , service_globalid
    , photo_globalid=photo_a_globalid 
    , AorB = convert(char(1), 'A')
    from #global
  union all
  select 
      globalid
    , service_globalid
    , photo_globalid=photo_b_globalid 
    , AorB = convert(char(1), 'B')
    from #global
    where photo_b_globalid is not null
    )
, x as (
  select 
      globalid
    , service_globalid
    , photo_globalid
    , seq = row_number() over (order by globalid asc, service_globalid, AorB  asc)
  from cte  
  )

  select 
      g.globalid
    , g.service_globalid
    , g.photo_a_globalid 
    , g.photo_b_globalid 
    , seq_a = xa.seq
    , seq_b = xb.seq
    from #global g 
      left join x as xa on g.globalid=xa.globalid and g.service_globalid=xa.service_globalid and g.photo_a_globalid=xa.photo_globalid
      left join x as xb on g.globalid=xb.globalid and g.service_globalid=xb.service_globalid and g.photo_b_globalid=xb.photo_globalid
    order by g.globalid, g.service_globalid
```

Comment: don't worked! on rextester, change in the line 3, `('EB8F9BE7' ,'0CD85BE7' ,'490794EC' , '181C5426')` to `('EB8F9BE7' ,'0CD85BE7' ,'490794EC' , null)` or include some more `NULL`s on `PHOTO_B_GLOBALID`

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky.  I would recommend doing a cumulative sum and some additional arithmetic:

```
select t.*,
       (sum(incThisRow) over (order by globalid, service_globalid) - incThisRow + 1
       ) as seq_A,
       (case when photo_b_globalid is not null
             then sum(incThisRow) over (order by globalid, service_globalid)
        end) as seq_B
from (select t.*,
             (case when PHOTO_B_GLOBALID is null then 1 else 2 end) as incThisRow
      from t
     ) t;
```

Comment: don't worked! `seq_a` = 1, `seq_b` = 1, then `seq_a` = 3, `seq_b` = 3, and finally `seq_a` = 5, `seq_b` = NULL

Comment: @RobertoCorreia . . . That seemed to be an off-by-one error on `seq_b`.  I think this is the simplest solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could...

- Unpivot the photo data into two sets (A,B) and union them
- eliminate the null photo's records from B & Number
- join back to base set to get full data

UNTESTED

```
With CTE AS (
SELECT GLOBALID, SERVICE_GLOBALID,  PHOTO_A_GLOBALID, 'a' as RowID
union
SELECT GLOBALID, SERVICE_GLOBALID,  PHOTO_B_GLOBALID, 'b'),

CTE2 as (
SELECT A.*, row_number() over order by (date) RN
FROM CTE A
WHERE PHOTO_B_GLOBALID is not null)

SELECT A.*, B.PHOTO_B_GLOBALID, A.RN as SEQ_A, B.RN as SEQ_B
FROM cte A
LEFT JOIN CTE2 B
  on A.GLOBALID =B.GLOBALID
 and A.SERVICE_GLOBALID = B.SERVICE_GLOBALID
 and A.RowID = 'a'
 and b.rowID = 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this...

```
;WITH cte
AS (SELECT *, RowN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) )
FROM (SELECT GLOBALID, SERVICE_GLOBALID, PHOTO_A_GLOBALID
FROM yourglobal WHERE PHOTO_A_GLOBALID IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT GLOBALID, SERVICE_GLOBALID, PHOTO_B_GLOBALID
FROM yourglobal WHERE PHOTO_B_GLOBALID IS NOT NULL) a)
SELECT
  yg.*, c.RowN AS SEQ_A, cb.RowN AS SEQ_B
FROM yourglobal yg
LEFT JOIN cte c
  ON yg.PHOTO_A_GLOBALID = c.PHOTO_A_GLOBALID
LEFT JOIN cte cb
  ON yg.PHOTO_B_GLOBALID = cb.PHOTO_A_GLOBALID
```